# read_table in pandas, how to get input from text to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

```
Alabama[edit]
Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
Alaska[edit]
Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
Arizona[edit]
Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
Tempe (Arizona State University)
Tucson (University of Arizona)
```

This is my text, i need to create a data frame with 1 column for the state name, and another column for the town name, i know how to remove the university names. but how do i tell pandas that at every [edit] is a new state.

expected output dataframe

```
Alabama Auburn
Alabama Florence 
Alabama Jacksonville
Alaska  Fairbanks 
Arizona Flagstaff
Arizona Tempe
Arizona Tucson
```

I am not sure if i can use read_table, if i can how? I did import everything into a dataframe but the state and the city are in the same column. Also i tried with a list, but the problem is still the same.

I need something that works like if there is a [edit] in the line then all the value after it and before the next [edit] line is the state of the lines in between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `pandas` can do it but you can do it easily.

```
data = '''Alabama[edit]
Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
Alaska[edit]
Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
Arizona[edit]
Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
Tempe (Arizona State University)
Tucson (University of Arizona)'''

# ---

result = []

state = None

for line in data.split('\n'):

    if line.endswith('[edit]'):
        # remember new state
        state = line[:-6] # without `[edit]`
    else:
        # add state, city to result
        city, rest = line.split(' ', 1)
        result.append( [state, city] )

# --- display ---

for state, city in result:
    print(state, city)
```

if you read from file then

```
result = []

state = None

with open('your_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() # remove '\n'

        if line.endswith('[edit]'):
            # remember new state
            state = line[:-6] # without `[edit]`
        else:
            # add state, city to result
            city, rest = line.split(' ', 1)
            result.append( [state, city] )

# --- display ---

for state, city in result:
    print(state, city)
```

Now you can use `result` to create `DataFrame`.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly. only  `city, rest = line.split(' ', 1)` doesn't work for something like New York but its easy to fix

Comment: probably `split(" (")` should work.

Comment: yeah i already fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Using Pandas, you could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\n', header=None, names=['town'])
df['is_state'] = df['town'].str.contains(r'\[edit\]')
df['groupno'] = df['is_state'].cumsum()
df['index'] = df.groupby('groupno').cumcount()
df['state'] = df.groupby('groupno')['town'].transform('first')
df['state'] = df['state'].str.replace(r'\[edit\]', '')
df['town'] = df['town'].str.replace(r' \(.+$', '')
df = df.loc[~df['is_state']]
df = df[['state','town']]
```

which yields

```
     state          town
1  Alabama        Auburn
2  Alabama      Florence
3  Alabama  Jacksonville
5   Alaska     Fairbanks
7  Arizona     Flagstaff
8  Arizona         Tempe
9  Arizona        Tucson
```

---

Here is a breakdown of what the code is doing. After loading the text file into a DataFrame, use `str.contains` to identify the rows which are states. Use `cumsum` to take a cumulative sum of the True/False values, where True is treated as 1 and False as 0.

```
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\n', header=None, names=['town'])
df['is_state'] = df['town'].str.contains(r'\[edit\]')
df['groupno'] = df['is_state'].cumsum()
#                                               town is_state  groupno
# 0                                    Alabama[edit]     True        1
# 1                    Auburn (Auburn University)[1]    False        1
# 2           Florence (University of North Alabama)    False        1
# 3  Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]    False        1
# 4                                     Alaska[edit]     True        2
# 5    Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]    False        2
# 6                                    Arizona[edit]     True        3
# 7       Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]    False        3
# 8                 Tempe (Arizona State University)    False        3
# 9                   Tucson (University of Arizona)    False        3
```

Now for each `groupno` number, we can assign a unique integer for each row in the group:

```
df['index'] = df.groupby('groupno').cumcount()
#                                               town is_state  groupno  index
# 0                                    Alabama[edit]     True        1      0
# 1                    Auburn (Auburn University)[1]    False        1      1
# 2           Florence (University of North Alabama)    False        1      2
# 3  Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]    False        1      3
# 4                                     Alaska[edit]     True        2      0
# 5    Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]    False        2      1
# 6                                    Arizona[edit]     True        3      0
# 7       Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]    False        3      1
# 8                 Tempe (Arizona State University)    False        3      2
# 9                   Tucson (University of Arizona)    False        3      3
```

Again for each `groupno` number, we can find the state by selecting the first town in each group:

```
df['state'] = df.groupby('groupno')['town'].transform('first')
#                                               town is_state  groupno  index          state
# 0                                    Alabama[edit]     True        1      0  Alabama[edit]
# 1                    Auburn (Auburn University)[1]    False        1      1  Alabama[edit]
# 2           Florence (University of North Alabama)    False        1      2  Alabama[edit]
# 3  Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]    False        1      3  Alabama[edit]
# 4                                     Alaska[edit]     True        2      0   Alaska[edit]
# 5    Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]    False        2      1   Alaska[edit]
# 6                                    Arizona[edit]     True        3      0  Arizona[edit]
# 7       Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]    False        3      1  Arizona[edit]
# 8                 Tempe (Arizona State University)    False        3      2  Arizona[edit]
# 9                   Tucson (University of Arizona)    False        3      3  Arizona[edit]
```

We basically have the desired DataFrame; all that's left is to prettify the result.
We can remove the `[edit]` from the `state`s and everything after the first parenthesis from the `town`s using `str.replace`:

```
df['state'] = df['state'].str.replace(r'\[edit\]', '')
df['town'] = df['town'].str.replace(r' \(.+$', '')
```

Remove the rows where the `town` is actually a state:

```
df = df.loc[~df['is_state']]
```

And finally, keep only the desired columns:

```
df = df[['state','town']]
```

Comment: this is great, but is it faster then a for loop and a list?

Comment: For a large enough text file, using Pandas' column-based vectorized functions should be faster than using a Python loop. For small files, the Python loop could be faster. For very large text files, the Pandas code should be much faster than equivalent code using a Python loop.

Comment: @lucarlig: After some benchmarking, it appears the Python loop is faster for any reasonable-sized file (after all, there aren't that many states and towns.) So really, furas' answer is the more practical solution.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!