# Extract Data from one column to another Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm following this link :

[Create Pandas DataFrame from txt file with specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386443/create-pandas-dataframe-from-txt-file-with-specific-pattern)

for solving the same  problem as mentioned in the link . But I'm getting this State column values as NaN regardless of the solution i'm following . This is the output:

RegionName   State

Alabama        NaN

Auburn         NaN

Florence       NaN

Jacksonville   NaN

Livingston     NaN

Montevallo     NaN

Now, how do i fill in these NaN values with State value

Comment: How do you initially read the text file?

Comment: In the answer on the link given, the first column is `'Region Name'`, but in your example here, it's `'RegionName'`. Any chance you just have a typo in the column name when you do the `extract` and `replace` commands?

Comment: I read the text file using read_csv. No,' Region Name' and 'RegionName' didnt make any difference