# Given conditions for list.append

Tags: python, pandas, append

I read a text file as lines and its first few lines look like this:

```
['Alabama[edit]\n',
 'Auburn (Auburn University)[1]\n',
 'Florence (University of North Alabama)\n',
 'Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]\n',
 'Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]\n',
 'Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]\n',
 'Troy (Troy University)[2]\n',
 'Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]\n',
 'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]\n',
 'Alaska[edit]\n',
 'Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]\n',
 'Arizona[edit]\n',
 'Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]\n',
 'Tempe (Arizona State University)\n',
 'Tucson (University of Arizona)\n',
```

I'd like to construct a dataframe out of it with states in one column and cities in the next column. I do it as:

```
    list = []
    for line in file:
        if '[edit]' in line:
            state = line.split('[edit]')[0]
        else:
            if '(' in line:
                region = line.split(' (')[0]
            else:
                region = line.split(' (')[0]

            list.append([state,region])

    df= pd.DataFrame(list, columns=["State", "RegionName"])
```

The output looks like this:

```
    State   RegionName
0   Alabama     Auburn
1   Alabama     Florence
2   Alabama     Jacksonville
3   Alabama     Livingston
4   Alabama     Montevallo
```

I think it works fine but my problem is the algorithm! I mean when the first line is read, we get state=Alabama, no "else" part is executed and we get to the append line where a state without region has to be added to the list in which case I would expect the first row without any regions and in order to solve that, I would use a line like:

```
if region != '':
```

before the append line but such line is not required since it works fine!
My understanding is that append is only executed if both state and region have values! 
If that is the case, (I know it sounds weird) but how should I have known about such hidden condition behind append function? Like is it mentioned somewhere in the manual? Or is there a general thing that I don't know about panda functions...
I hope my question makes any sense!
Thank you

Comment: Please check this [solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41386443/2901002)

Comment: Your `list.append` call is indented so that it will only be called once you are in a line which contains a '(', which is not a line containing `[edit]`. Therefore, there will never be a line appended which only contains the state.