# Create a dataframe with multiple columns from a dataframe of single column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

1 stname1
2 regionname1(of state 1)
3 regionname2
....
15 stname2
16 regioname1(of state 2)
..and so on.

I wish to convert the above data frame into something like this:
1 stname1 regionname1
2 stname1 regionname2
.....
15 stname2 regionname1
16 stname2 regionname2
and so on.

Being a newbie into python, it would be a great help if someone can explain the above problem with any suitable type of example.

Comment: Maybe help check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41386443/2901002)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer....it works perfectly but I am having some difficulty in understanding the code. Can you please share some documentation so that I can learn about it.

Comment: You can check original [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings)

Comment: Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: No problem. Only one small advice if some question in future - check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Nice day!

Comment: Okay sure. Being new to the community I did know about this but from the next time I will take care.