# UnboundLocalError in Pandas

Tags: pandas

My task is to clean the data and present it in next format: DataFrame( [ ["Michigan", "Ann Arbor"], ["Michigan", "Yipsilanti"] ], columns=["State", "RegionName"]  ).

I'm getting a mistake. How can I fix it?
**"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'state' referenced before assignment"**

The code is following:

```
 with open ('university_towns.txt') as file:
    data=[]
    for line in file:
        data.append(line[:-1])
state_town = []

for line in data:
    if line[:-6]=='[edit]':
        state=line[:-6]
    elif '(' in line:
        town = line[:line.index('(')-1]
        state_town.append([state,town])
    else:
        town=line
        state_town.append([state,town])
    state_college_df=pd.DataFrame(state_town, columns=['State','RegionName'])
return state_college_df
```

Comment: You need to declare `state` outside your conditional statements

Comment: Can you add some data sample and desired output? I believe loops are not necessary.

Comment: @jezrael thanks! The sample of data is following:

"Alabama[edit]
Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Alaska[edit]
Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
Arizona[edit]
Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]

It has to look like DataFrame where the first column contains the name of state and the second-the name of the region, like this:

State RegionName
0 Alabama Auburn
1 Alabama Florence
2 Alaska Fairbanks
3 Arizona Flagstaff

Comment: It is from wikipedia? What is source?

Comment: @jezrael yes, Wikipedia)

Comment: I think you need one of these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41386443/2901002)