# Create multi-column Pandas DataFrame from txt file with one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file that has one column in the format as below. Strings followed by [edit] are state names, and followed by () are regions of each state. I want to create a Pandas DataFrame that puts state in one column and region in another column. For cleaner data, I will also strip things within and after [] or ().

```
 ['Alabama[edit]\n',
 'Auburn (Auburn University)[1]\n',
 'Florence (University of North Alabama)\n',
 'Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]\n',
 'Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]\n',
 'Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]\n',
 'Troy (Troy University)[2]\n',
 'Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]\n',
 'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]\n',
 'Alaska[edit]\n',
 'Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]\n',
 'Arizona[edit]\n',
 'Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]\n',
 'Tempe (Arizona State University)\n',
 'Tucson (University of Arizona)\n',
```

Here's my code:

```
 with open('university_towns.txt') as f:
      f=f.readlines()
      for line in f:

        lst = []
        state = ''
        region = ''
        dict1={}

        if line.endswith('[ed'):
            state = line.split('[')[0]    
        else:
            if line.find ('(') > 0:
                region = line.split(' ')[0]          
            else:
                region = line.split('\n')[0].strip()
        dict1.update({'RegionName':region, 'State':state})
        lst.append (dict1)
        lst = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["State", "RegionName"])
```

I get a weird looking dataframe with 2 columns and 1 row that has no state name...I wonder what I did wrong and how to fix?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386443/create-pandas-dataframe-from-txt-file-with-specific-pattern

Comment: I saw the other post, but I hope someone could clarify what's wrong with my way of doing it.