# Matching states and cities with possibly multiple words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a Python list like the following elements:

```
['Alabama[edit]',
 'Auburn (Auburn University)[1]',
 'Florence (University of North Alabama)',
 'Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]',
 'Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]',
 'Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]',
 'Troy (Troy University)[2]',
 'Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]',
 'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]',
 'Alaska[edit]',
 'Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]',
 'Arizona[edit]',
 'Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]',
 'Tempe (Arizona State University)',
 'Tucson (University of Arizona)',
 'Arkansas[edit]',
 'Arkadelphia (Henderson State University, Ouachita Baptist University)[2]',
 'Conway (Central Baptist College, Hendrix College, University of Central Arkansas)[2]',
 'Fayetteville (University of Arkansas)[7]']
```

The list is not complete, but is sufficient to give you an idea of what's in it.

The data is structured like this:

There is a name of a US state and following the state name, there are some names of cities IN THAT STATE. The state name, as you can see ends in "[edit]", and the cities' name either end in a bracket with a number (for example "[1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fun9wuneVNjKZLUXtQIDWmZFAsMoTh-8)", or   "[2]"), or with a university's name within parenthesis (for example "(University of North Alabama)").

(Find the full reference file for this problem [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fun9wuneVNjKZLUXtQIDWmZFAsMoTh-8))

I ideally want a Python dictionary with the state names as the index, and all the cities' names in that state in a nested listed as a value to that particular index. So, for example the dictionary should be like:

```
{'Alabama': ['Auburn', 'Florence', 'Jacksonville'...], 'Arizona': ['Flagstaff', 'Temple', 'Tucson', ....], ......}
```

Now, I tried the following solution, to weed out the unnecessary parts:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

    def get_list_of_university_towns():
        '''
        Returns a DataFrame of towns and the states they are in from the 
        university_towns.txt list. The format of the DataFrame should be:
        DataFrame( [ ["Michigan", "Ann Arbor"], ["Michigan", "Yipsilanti"] ], 
        columns=["State", "RegionName"]  )

        The following cleaning needs to be done:

        1. For "State", removing characters from "[" to the end.
        2. For "RegionName", when applicable, removing every character from " (" to the end.
        3. Depending on how you read the data, you may need to remove newline character '\n'. 

        '''

        fhandle = open("university_towns.txt")
        ftext = fhandle.read().split("\n")

        reftext = list()
        for item in ftext:
            reftext.append(item.split(" ")[0])

        #pos = reftext[0].find("[")
        #reftext[0] = reftext[0][:pos]

        towns = list()
        dic = dict()

        for item in reftext:
            if item == "Alabama[edit]":
                state = "Alabama"

            elif item.endswith("[edit]"):
                dic[state] = towns
                towns = list()
                pos = item.find("[")
                item = item[:pos]
                state = item

            else:
                towns.append(item)

        return ftext

    get_list_of_university_towns()
```

A snippet of my output generated by my code looks like this:

```
{'Alabama': ['Auburn',
  'Florence',
  'Jacksonville',
  'Livingston',
  'Montevallo',
  'Troy',
  'Tuscaloosa',
  'Tuskegee'],
 'Alaska': ['Fairbanks'],
 'Arizona': ['Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tucson'],
 'Arkansas': ['Arkadelphia',
  'Conway',
  'Fayetteville',
  'Jonesboro',
  'Magnolia',
  'Monticello',
  'Russellville',
  'Searcy'],
 'California': ['Angwin',
  'Arcata',
  'Berkeley',
  'Chico',
  'Claremont',
  'Cotati',
  'Davis',
  'Irvine',
  'Isla',
  'University',
  'Merced',
  'Orange',
  'Palo',
  'Pomona',
  'Redlands',
  'Riverside',
  'Sacramento',
  'University',
  'San',
  'San',
  'Santa',
  'Santa',
  'Turlock',
  'Westwood,',
  'Whittier'],
 'Colorado': ['Alamosa',
  'Boulder',
  'Durango',
  'Fort',
  'Golden',
  'Grand',
  'Greeley',
  'Gunnison',
  'Pueblo,'],
 'Connecticut': ['Fairfield',
  'Middletown',
  'New',
  'New',
  'New',
  'Storrs',
  'Willimantic'],
 'Delaware': ['Dover', 'Newark'],
 'Florida': ['Ave',
  'Boca',
  'Coral',
  'DeLand',
  'Estero',
  'Gainesville',
  'Orlando',
  'Sarasota',
  'St.',
  'St.',
  'Tallahassee',
  'Tampa'],
 'Georgia': ['Albany',
  'Athens',
  'Atlanta',
  'Carrollton',
  'Demorest',
  'Fort',
  'Kennesaw',
  'Milledgeville',
  'Mount',
  'Oxford',
  'Rome',
  'Savannah',
  'Statesboro',
  'Valdosta',
  'Waleska',
  'Young'],
 'Hawaii': ['Manoa'],
```

But, there is one error in the output: States with a space in their names (e.g. "North Carolina") are not included. I can the the reason behind it.

I thought of using regular expressions, but since I have yet to study about them, I do not know how to form one. Any ideas as to how it could be done with or without the use of Regex?

Comment: Can you include your current output as well? (Unrelated: can you come up with a better title for your question?)

Comment: Is `ftext` contain the given list `['Alabama[edit]',
 'Auburn (Auburn Univer...`?

Comment: @Math10 Yes. ftext contains the given list.

Comment: [This](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26299114/) will help you.

Comment: @Math10 Thanks for taking the pain of finding that for me bro, but I do not want to just copy and paste. This is part of a graded academic assignment and I do not intend to take help more than what is allowed. Could find me in trouble.

Comment: @usr2564301 Included my output. Sorry for the title, but when I posted, Stackoverflow warned me about my original title. This was what I could think of.

Comment: OK. Let me tell you the main problem only.
`reftext.append(item.split(" ")[0])` here you only take the 1st string in this case. This is the reason you didn't find the proper result for "North Carolina"  ( you will find "North" instead of "North Carolina"). Because a space contain between North Carolina.

Comment: @Math10 I got why "North Carolina" and others are not present. What I did not get though, is why are there ALL the towns present under every state.

Comment: Ideally, a title should describe the problem itself, not that you have one :P How's this? No need to repeat what's in your tags. I find no reference to Pandas so I removed that tag.

Comment: Um. Other than the `import pandas` line then. Is it relevant to your code and/or desired answer? If not, then it can be left out.

Comment: @usr2564301 This is actually a subset of a bigger problem with is essentially a Pandas problem. The dictionary will be ultimately loaded into a Pandas dataframe. I had just included the tag to make it easier for my fellow classmates to find this question, in case they had a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [c/sh]ould change

```
fhandle = open("university_towns.txt")
ftext = fhandle.read().split("\n") 

# to

with open("university_towns.txt","r") as f:
    d = f.readlines()

# file is autoclosed here, lines are autosplit by readlines()
```

No regex solution:

```
def save(state,city,dic):
    '''convenience fnkt to add or create set entry with list of city'''
    if state in dic:
        dic[state].append(city)
    else:
        dic[state] = [] # fix for glitch

dic = {}
state = "" 

with open("university_towns.txt","r") as f:
    d = f.readlines()  

for n in d:                                         # iterate all lines
    if "[edit]" in n:                                   # handles states
        act_state = n.replace("[edit]","").strip()      # clean up state
        # needed in case 2 states w/o cities follow right after each other
        save(act_state,"", dic)                         # create state in dic, no cities
        state = n.replace("[edit]","").strip()      # clean up state
    else:
        # splits at ( takes first and splits at [ takes first removes blanks
        #   => get city name before ( or [
        city = n.split("(")[0].split("[")[0].strip()  
        save(state,city,dic)                            # adds city to state in dic

print (dic)
```

Yields (re-formatted):

```
{
 'Alabama' : ['Auburn', 'Florence', 'Jacksonville', 'Livingston',
              'Montevallo', 'Troy', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Tuskegee'], 
 'Alaska'  : ['Fairbanks'], 
 'Arizona' : ['Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tucson'], 
 'Arkansas': ['Arkadelphia', 'Conway', 'Fayetteville']
}
```

Comment: Let me get back to you by tonight.

Comment: Fantastic man!! Almost worked for me. Although other people's code did also work, and I thank them immensely for spending their time to help, your code was the most simple and understandable.
But there is a little glitch. At the beginning of every state's city list, there is a blank list in addition to the cities. E.g. {'Alaska': [ [] , 'Fairbanks' ]}. So here, there should be just "Fairbanks" for Alaska, but there is an additional list to be found. Same for every other state. Anyway, I am working on it. Much thanks.

Comment: @ArchanJoshi Fixed the code - `dic[state] = [] # fix for glitch` and for good measure: `save(act_state,"", dic)` as the 2nd param is not used

Answer (score 4):

Praise the power of regular expressions then:

```
states_rx = re.compile(r'''
^
(?P<state>.+?)\[edit\]
(?P<cities>[\s\S]+?)
(?=^.*\[edit\]$|\Z)
''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

cities_rx = re.compile(r'''^[^()\n]+''', re.MULTILINE)

transformed = '\n'.join(lst_)

result = {state.group('state'): [city.group(0).rstrip() 
        for city in cities_rx.finditer(state.group('cities'))] 
        for state in states_rx.finditer(transformed)}
print(result)
```

This yields

```
{'Alabama': ['Auburn', 'Florence', 'Jacksonville', 'Livingston', 'Montevallo', 'Troy', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Tuskegee'], 'Alaska': ['Fairbanks'], 'Arizona': ['Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tucson'], 'Arkansas': ['Arkadelphia', 'Conway', 'Fayetteville']}
```

---

#### Explanation:

The idea is to split the task up into several smaller tasks:

1. Join the complete list with `\n`
2. Separate states
3. Separate towns
4. Use a dict comprehension for all found items

---

**First subtask**

```
transformed = '\n'.join(your_list)
```

**Second subtask**

```
^                      # match start of the line
(?P<state>.+?)\[edit\] # capture anything in that line up to [edit]
(?P<cities>[\s\S]+?)   # afterwards match anything up to
(?=^.*\[edit\]$|\Z)    # ... either another state or the very end of the string
```

See [**the demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ht9rTp/4).

**Third subtask**

```
^[^()\n]+              # match start of the line, anything not a newline character or ( or )
```

See [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ht9rTp/2).

**Fourth subtask**

```
result = {state.group('state'): [city.group(0).rstrip() for city in cities_rx.finditer(state.group('cities'))] for state in states_rx.finditer(transformed)}
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
for state in states_rx.finditer(transformed):
    # state is in state.group('state')
    for city in cities_rx.finditer(state.group('cities')):
        # city is in city.group(0), possibly with whitespaces
        # hence the rstrip
```

---

Lastly, some timing issues:

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(findstatesandcities, number=10**5))
# 12.234304904000965
```

So running the above a **100.000** times took me round 12 seconds on my computer, so it should be reasonably fast.

Comment: I need a little break. Will get back to you by tonight. Seems like the solution could work, but the provided code is too complex. Man, I never saw anything like it ever before. How much experience do you have with Python, btw?

Comment: @ArchanJoshi: Thanks. I have tweaked the code a little and added explanations. Admittedly, I do have some experience in `Python` and general programming logic. However, `Python` is a fantastic language offering e.g. list or dict comprehensions which you will hardly find in other languages. Plus, you have an uncountable number of libraries at your fingertips.

Comment: @ArchanJoshi Python is relatively easy to learn. But there is a lot in the language and standard library. And regular expressions are in fact a separate domain specific language. So it will take time and affort to master it all. Don't let that discourage you.

Comment: @RolandSmith: Right. And sometimes it does not even need a regular expression but often it makes the code more concise and easier to read once you get the hang of it.

Comment: @Jan I fully agree that regular expressions are consise. And powerful. But I would say "easy to read" is debatable. Let me just say that `re.VERBOSE` exists for a reason. :-)

Comment: @RolandSmith: 1:0 for you, here :)

Comment: @Jan I figured that you are a seasoned Python programmer. There's no way a beginner can write that much complicated code. I have been learning Python since June 2017, and embarrassingly enough, this is the first time I heard about "dictionary comprehension".
I'll come to your answer again sometime in the future when I have a higher grasp on the language. For now, I am going forward with something within my comprehension capabilities. Thanks a lot, anyway.

Comment: @RolandSmith The only thing that can discourage me from learning Python is if it would be discontinued as a language. I am a Python convert from Java, and since that fortunate day, I have never thought of going back. But the fact that there are hundreds of libraries make learning Python a little scary task.

Comment: @Jan (also to Roland) Can one of you suggest to me a good place where I can learn Python regex FROM THE BEGINNING. Pay attention to "FROM THE BEGINNING". I used to be a pro in regex in Java till 2015, but now I am ashamed to say that I forgot everything.

Comment: I would say start with the [regex HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html) from the Python documentation and follow with the [`re` chapter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) from the standard library documentation.

Comment: @ArchanJoshi: I'd say that https://regexone.com/ would be a good starting point. As for `Python` itself, https://learnpythonthehardway.org/ might be of interest. Additionally, if one of the answers provided helped you, please consider accepting (and/or upvoting) it (green tick on the left). This does not necessarily have to be mine though.

Comment: @Jan Seems like multiple answers could work. Choosing just one amongst the many is a real dilemma. I feel like that would be a disservice to those who spent their time in helping me and yet did not get theirs green ticked. Is it mandatory to choose an accepted answer?

Comment: @ArchanJoshi: Accept the one you're most comfortable with and upvote the others.

Comment: @Jan Done the same. Much thanks for your valuable insight, and your guidance regarding regex. I will start soon. Will also learn about dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @Jan I have posted another question at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093234/pandas-please-explain-how-does-a-double-for-work

Can you please explain. I am grateful.

Comment: @ArchanJoshi: As jezrael points out, maybe one of these answers is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386443/create-pandas-dataframe-from-txt-file-with-specific-pattern

Answer (score 3):

Let's solve your problem step by step :

> First step:

collect all the data and here i am using putting a track word whenever any  state name appear it put a word 'pos_flag' so with the help of this word we will track and chunk:

```
import re
pattern='\w+(?=\[edit\])'

track=[]
with open('mon.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match=re.search(pattern,line)
        if match:
            track.append('pos_flag')
            track.append(line.strip().split('[')[0])
        else:

            track.append(line.strip().split('(')[0])
```

it will give something like this output:

```
['pos_flag', 'Alabama', 'Auburn ', 'Florence ', 'Jacksonville ', 'Livingston ', 'Montevallo ', 'Troy ', 'Tuscaloosa ', 'Tuskegee ', 'pos_flag', 'Alaska', 'Fairbanks ', 'pos_flag', 'Arizona', 'Flagstaff ', 'Tempe ', 'Tucson ', 'pos_flag', 'Arkansas', 'Arkadelphia ', 'Conway ', 'Fayetteville ', 'Jonesboro ', 'Magnolia ', 'Monticello ', 'Russellville ', 'Searcy ', 'pos_flag',
```

As you can see before every state name there is a word 'pos_flag' now let's use this word and do some stuff:

> Second step:

Track the index of all the 'pos_flag words' in list:

```
index_no=[]
for index,value in enumerate(track):
    if value=='pos_flag':
        index_no.append(index)
```

This will give output something like this :

```
[0, 10, 13, 18, 28, 55, 66, 75, 79, 93, 111, 114, 119, 131, 146, 161, 169, 182, 192, 203, 215, 236, 258, 274, 281, 292, 297, 306, 310, 319, 331, 338, 371, 391, 395, 419, 432, 444, 489, 493, 506, 512, 527, 551, 559, 567, 581, 588, 599, 614]
```

We have now index no and we can chunk the link with these index numbers :

> Last step:

chunk the list with using index no and set first word as dict key and rest of as dict values:

```
city_dict={}
for i in range(0,len(index_no),1):
    try:
        value_1=track[index_no[i:i + 2][0]:index_no[i:i + 2][1]]
        city_dict[value_1[1]]=value_1[2:]
    except IndexError:
        city_dict[track[index_no[i:i + 2][0]:][1]]=track[index_no[i:i + 2][0]:][1:]

print(city_dict)
```

output:

since dict are not ordered in python 3.5 so order of output is different from input file :

```
{'Kentucky': ['Bowling Green ', 'Columbia ', 'Georgetown ', 'Highland Heights ', 'Lexington ', 'Louisville ', 'Morehead ', 'Murray ', 'Richmond ', 'Williamsburg ', 'Wilmore '], 'Mississippi': ['Cleveland ', 'Hattiesburg ', 'Itta Bena ', 'Oxford ', 'Starkville '], 'Wisconsin': ['Appleton ', 'Eau Claire ', 'Green Bay ', 'La Crosse ', 'Madison ', 'Menomonie ', 'Milwaukee ',
```

full_code:

```
import re
pattern='\w+(?=\[edit\])'

track=[]
with open('mon.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match=re.search(pattern,line)
        if match:
            track.append('pos_flag')
            track.append(line.strip().split('[')[0])
        else:

            track.append(line.strip().split('(')[0])


index_no=[]
for index,value in enumerate(track):
    if value=='pos_flag':
        index_no.append(index)


city_dict={}
for i in range(0,len(index_no),1):
    try:
        value_1=track[index_no[i:i + 2][0]:index_no[i:i + 2][1]]
        city_dict[value_1[1]]=value_1[2:]
    except IndexError:
        city_dict[track[index_no[i:i + 2][0]:][1]]=track[index_no[i:i + 2][0]:][1:]

print(city_dict)
```

> Second solution:

If you want to use regex then try this small solution :

```
import re
pattern='((\w+\[edit\])(?:(?!^\w+\[edit\]).)*)'
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    prt=re.finditer(pattern,f.read(),re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

    for line in prt:
        dict_p={}
        match = []
        match.append(line.group(1))
        dict_p[match[0].split('\n')[0].strip().split('[')[0]]= [i.split('(')[0].strip() for i in match[0].split('\n')[1:][:-1]]

        print(dict_p)
```

it will give:

```
{'Alabama': ['Auburn', 'Florence', 'Jacksonville', 'Livingston', 'Montevallo', 'Troy', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Tuskegee']}
{'Alaska': ['Fairbanks']}
{'Arizona': ['Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tucson']}
{'Arkansas': ['Arkadelphia', 'Conway', 'Fayetteville', 'Jonesboro', 'Magnolia', 'Monticello', 'Russellville', 'Searcy']}
{'California': ['Angwin', 'Arcata', 'Berkeley', 'Chico', 'Claremont', 'Cotati', 'Davis', 'Irvine', 'Isla Vista', 'University Park, Los Angeles', 'Merced', 'Orange', 'Palo Alto', 'Pomona', 'Redlands', 'Riverside', 'Sacramento', 'University District, San Bernardino', 'San Diego', 'San Luis Obispo', 'Santa Barbara', 'Santa Cruz', 'Turlock', 'Westwood, Los Angeles', 'Whittier']}
{'Colorado': ['Alamosa', 'Boulder', 'Durango', 'Fort Collins', 'Golden', 'Grand Junction', 'Greeley', 'Gunnison', 'Pueblo, Colorado']}
```

[demo :](https://regex101.com/r/V0H5vz/7)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Code worked. Thanks for spending the time to help me. I'm grateful. Although your code is fully competent of earning a green-tick, I just went with another simpler to code. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to eliminate the need for more than [one regex](https://regex101.com/r/5hS8ET/3).

```
import re

def mkdict(data):
  state, dict = None, {}
  rx = re.compile(r'^(?:(.+\[edit\])|([^\(\n:]+))', re.M)
  for m in rx.finditer(data):
    if m.groups()[0]:
      state = m.groups()[0].rstrip('[edit]')
      dict[state] = []
    else:
      dict[state].append(m.groups()[1].rstrip())
  return dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys, timeit, functools
  data = sys.stdin.read()
  print(timeit.Timer(functools.partial(mkdict, data)).timeit(10**3))
  print(mkdict(data))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jT1rc9s4kt/1K1j7YSLtyq6ZndvXVG1d@e0kduKznKSmstkURMIiThShAUnLyt1V7X/Yf7h/ZK678SZBeatmIpBoPNho9Bvwdt@Wsv7x11/FZitVmyk@mRT8MdusC5G304K1bPbTJMualrV8nuHL7K/ZO1nDw//8H1SoZ3hW/DiXm62o@FS9@vv0P3@aHv/ub595Idq/fZn97/Tz3/82/Vv905ffzWav5gh8O4OWj1Jlm0zU0MXxo6gBmCs/YJYJmMXxSslu20xnn7//ot@aqcCgUeWxalolttNXNOqXVzMDjBP@TC2@QJPPX@g1rxr@0xDgmG23vC6mQcc/uI5n2KPibadqajOZwPy@fq3Zhn/9mv31r9mrr183TNRfv77Crg06m30zz1qx4aKdZ49dnbdSVg3U43fChKD@uGkLUR8rzoopjrFVom6nus3xA/yoqWt4vGWqFaya6uWZUzez2bGGnv7w/W9/@@PMdxIu4uzXX08qtmQbpjE0OemW@C1T8/uhFk9cNaLd41dPLiupeJ3zbOorMvkIK6/aMjM9zSZvWL5uZP0kqgpAo6cFLVPY7e@/TG7Ek6hXTSvrfsefeNO6fhH0VtYtf2JVJfugvoYAH5TcZ1P6tzfaQ9fkrJKyYf0uzEBzmCVMdsPq7EzCpFdA1YuSVzg/mv/s849fPv8H9bSGWvhGVwrH@gOgs2LN2uL2kgm1ZPW6SYwLUJmrp2meKPFN1q5txQBB7PExmxKyOSyOgYjG/CPMim@2MCVbO8A4TDtvhqg28DMYeM3qhjWWIuCx4NW2FICva9gJ0MQiIuh2nr3vWF4KIOBTtm0FrFsP72ey3jFYkzNet4pVDszhGDtX4tm/iCdo29n5UaeXbM9bWHdNav0vsoB/@jJ5A8ypWUolETP6fYIY/wwUxla1rPBjF7KziDYNel@EJCdyniBG14K1mYeiRvdd08CDmbEDfOB52e9/wZnKAWPXTAEzWPWJ64xVAthlLdzmrVc74JzTO5aLR5EjvHQ0bIgqRxYzve42S1kVbQIF0PEpV2te8X3/q/yA88zC6JmUIgcc@PoEeRCMJoSKKb4BrEALV7zN3/IayNUt/p3cyPAZkPAEU7rtiiLYljlw4W0TtBLtN67881uer7MrxYoO5/O6blrRdiiz/Miuto9eCd8gXviqhaylYU3n7Ek0h1BGAMRHXytgePwQrIaYTV43Fcs@wjZhh6AXrKZ9B@xD6ckEsHdMrefZjWwyoA9YssEcHZ37LmeTW65yXhwaVEPMJu8Vg34BTyXbIs8MWc0dMFpgby0QB@CuhqZFXK8XGXEMC17tzarPifHDlD7MPv/ly@cfvof/f/iSsbpA/QCEn4O0Kz2550UF9YOPs@9nk3v9ujiIdwc0D14nOBogFMhBcKUi/jtZsFyB8K/bl7aDB5yFi3UuULFAIQ5ripuspr3/cm8h8Dw7ARyJHF4uUOFoelOsYRi@ki9QlAYKiglRgnU3HZD9@6VotvEscT1b4Go1cKKk2I@oNpteCl4Rm0tsyB6JZ2c45TE5MbYxNFXRng95ooY5U923l7cYQhklQlUSWMsLywI0L2AHd0B@OPZOyuLgVgxHDMBoyE8gXFuguGzqSuYz7oXMrmVdSPddwLxAVWOFtJKhYhtSeE4KtrGCL0TCqeyqAvvuzcd0g3LMgAADQ2bX4a6HBb9EhfaG70QT9Uev8YWo4SNdN0M6@OHHL5MrEEW8DsHyEhRb0uqACwLygCRg779BjRdFmoe85U28Aa8UT4kupzTZlgDZ1bA42JthNgm03HV8WcEecOONf8qRhkXU1zWHeeZdGyh@j0jdgC5X7DMDYLbXIO8jtWlyK4qi4q3c6VnCh/UY7Du@y04VaF0o962GFMwgsWexyTV7QoT/zKqYYHtIs5DzQEYc6Bv4TrXkqu2aDLWoLpDL/9UJwPZWsDxefdCicZQbpF5aV9@7394LKDNgv1cd8LfsJAd9dAOD3Yo2B7W8indzK5Ua7ivfr95LoH0JEFbwJpteML38B9FGEp5XbAdqg1nWc/mEO8a@TRE3fR3I3/58bBtnVYnCKXFPHLCnUAH1xXD9TmXOsntG1pJpmp20lf6YEPBMIjFcsWWC0dwKthEz@KIb3FggnHmLW6GnAl0gYqQf5qqrHs1aRHuO4S5N6uCmpeWfl357gd6AgnkohQwRm5YoYxRrJCpASCmmedT3PUiNCiVHUHkCOwk/7Zw3YlXP470dtb5lNVTxIztOfxcQ6VvwzEIdmWYwv/Y4O@lWHaiWqNOhpVZ53qzrbzhpQLoQ2WJgsLKSgUnAPZqH@8qt83e3veabLUvqcx5/V1yqlbcRKjAxgT2a3yF7OIF9Xg/oxXQC9IpWLVEbjGveJiZsa9CsmWcXG6mMEciUAsSMmfpumN9/@e05Kysw2lbMmLyuT7uI343tUhgNO5veCV4MxD1Jpo@AdhQS4UOyMzRKQMTssqkrDVF2i5RfrKwV@m/O81Z2MLWPwHkQGaeK7wArR6itB9SDgO@fSW@eml9HWPdyA6OB2qf2oaMCPgk6iLW0Jwa2VYnm5gb0SwlbxXGMlDJpwA9Uje40pHdoZUxtRyBWfPQYDKC@kGTcuFISV59AUKGLZHrPRV2CFIjX9GdA5QotRIUWWPQUgl0DzxXCbATYv3KwdTQEWe1YTa1eF6y0etStbHK567ciCK0vAG9utUOAXqa/5p4/Lzu1grX7@cORb/watSUprOMFtsoSxCKKaO@KsDAhj/KAxhhHpgBL8a9//PMDOpQGX@k6ge/UEADqmtlOFKCc9qmVj4mxzYZ7y6pl4JgaA7woQOYVVlAc/KYQVLcFwtPToWF2RmXrexI5fA0CkTuhUHy461guN0uv843NFUbZgBSauvrkSt4BfaOkPgWVEHlIuOte14VgzoF3Wkm5ARlFn2Cqwg8O6vUCKLbD7W6x9YktWVP6zY96bp3DymDlOb9j3a6/ua4BFaSh2EK4F1CvCKeS0i4JDnRugWwGmGQaB@/ZGgW5tsmm0VOf7kVeAj8ukKRUBfQWa24ktk451r@TLShU52AgB30AEEg8YHcc9mkHE3GTHzKqe9nwo@uOnLjO64O0jwKpBh1@paf0YUuznT6wPcjL/oSBKW1B3oOVQAzKlsNVJrF1wx61HxJkTqeKboCj13LnBPAGtTF8kUbnGS@Yyi4B3c2oEYOtA@B7thVFM6fXqEN7PQc1vBzUQGD9N7TbPMb/4JynMMx2C1XUvDebKwV6O@rYU1dyPaAqQG30yvd4DE0RQW7A9KwFdsByTtg@IAjnOH8VjWMdTHqUaPdH5CNk90zaIynlsi8j0DDYwEqtkZg7Xlu32kDSPJF7CTacaolLh528DT3jsCUK9LfqiZ2ydSx2SYHGgA8yCFtILvk12zdGF6FiOkjCdsnYi54S@kebNaJN74nsHUNLOWZruBog10rWtgAxfZv2gpNGbGDOSpChrWB1vOp3om0bLcJ8cUx/art8vbcok7tKu3g4DwxvCzUMGVTdZon4uxF10QCDBcOt6fm0SccwNnJQduRzLVYlkd01h1LbBIIqNS7IkGfLp3uYNtDz7AEostlXIJIi2wxX/EZ2Im0K@RrQGEFDLTkDxuNKaR2xUwpjJuY36a0PuephdJLVyzZm5eLZAUKyM0A2V9pdauBRlQa1EZvsY0tfv3ooOTJTkYOsXHAQYMwo@vS1ofwjg/VedugqdpVJj/pQVUT/z2ZJlDP1xSQ2rtlGI0P3YzDiBxzsKse5E6tFLVjA33HlaiUPQ2sQrUWwFmNiMi950@Ndac2w0zqO7y8VF3ooxVIWDNjd9B0svkRRkSYfNMxdZBdN1IEuSCA4a1OvvYEgVK5Rq1Tk8LKaPtKItRtmk1PV1c1OoBMUtnUhRbDnLpnapDeRG8@DeLMMCXe8gYUAcpAKtYexOAY1MfrgTiBG56Yb4NJgm4SiRdYyOaIRBrBUZjM/lHLDAo8WFJZ73xPoU3vcOS4UV7OtrExAqOVmfzfAl58whml9WOgTeCPL@lUwqbOSSMR4/UDrM5gMmZ5dlbuEc8lOZZ6FUMC5/wjt3BZHFwBUohMgWGLbdgaiayMsk9cSGueK9a8GyvKlAtNNg/picnvegRaR8wY928MAmB08s4wMjVmtqjzIHblqzW/kapBdXva02wUD1BODmvpinxtiMEDUDekLt/k5MHNehQvaNCwvuwb2vZP4Um9P8xvOwrxy5OGe6wZICJifAiB0YF3UK60gRzWn6ODmkRkyN/oe61s68@wDTs4Mgd4V0HI7P3foratRGbkWpEZtNl0dxUvu5TMhJFG16B4fZbWOObJAlhqQPip0q2yDpCNxxzXIDESx4jtGyAwfhj71M@DfBECB7Semip7yEeB9VHef3pC9EkeYXcdupjcw0X0YTugaYF2kw9Auq7tWY2karx/YGaXrpiH3lFQ5bUtaOFgY0W1@mpx3ZPYZNhzsYeOxUuyRCAa2HTK7JpjKRw6dkbzMboG6csPlHrrHXrzujj1TH8hSjDvYDeNnBTK66TZbVPowOJ/D@usgd7yW1xhkPYM92mhMH4eb/w6M/g3L99l3GIqo4AMWYPvhftUO/EasGAnXBOFokqQvQVWAPnMeYG0o6H1dGCl0C66X4BLg3RTv@QptVuMs1Jw@IJafwLZCagQRYgtB9sBmC4xU8bGoYUx2pr2mFFpLaE@rsACuGJjh2mi91ta/4ZOIY7kOPN2XGKgw7NEV441hCEaH56bxZIIVuhHAvSkHpoVNt8CErpWJLLmQ72u0gGpS/5nnZ2BYheD@NYkCi8@YQVkiQ1JAcQu2edvzcszJ99FnXTOnahohZp4ClIAWB5OhboNyyrcKChRIKStXC4XWyNT8er4l0KKzGn7kz66W5Ogwv96O@RM6wytuPGw6wjjmCgbIDQZk8F/3DbAhYSFISeoHV/ScKbqD/lmYXKax3@A@LhTfDWToqVgZQx4wwsl3mdTpUDaCQgqbEbVhO1Qa9hL05BZd1y3xmtWBWJ/t6IjaoNUEWqVGjS96mwr0@JL2g5uAY87EAHpi/y2r2IZ9k9KTmmsYzsnD9XxVv3RaSXemW6K5hhWF1m60si1lnHCid@hdBVKVUQKSiTaNdfe@gkeAM7@xjrEC9r1DDUMXRolnwboK1SdO@hN608gNsei2sCpSpVoQsVjqip56E/x52wjSyL35N44ajGDI1plkYK8V/y1wX@tC2h@lpFyncjNdd5kD0e7grkKeOAqt6@dZjAO3kwPBS0o9KJ0oTSr4OKCsPtl@Ek0ucS/86x//tH3NzRCgBjUYmAy3GlomYonrYSzNzAfNdSLRLavXDNN3/IyTHhIEms3hg0HaAnsEXUh72DxXQrptSvSbamMULb9svFfjCwPTRjsGDg1voFDDr3OpikAn@PwDJjFKHQoZWwNdbx3dbWlkyBk6/SM1FtH/vmKPkd9QyyqDgzE8YsuzSnaFDnzq4vBTDi@38dyhjdTwbRlZowuGzA1kEuocrYO846QOXaEx@9SBKC9ktS27OBL0SdSUd2Z@U5k7CVsnwiEg@i@4p5oG/9tubVzprOJP2s2JmQHtqMsPM3iSnhhvxvq@oc33XyavW0xmQkE3DeoOxi9t7LD/EWHPiDfQE42dG/acJlGolZ0SziYC1shUSONjCcBsy7MroUDj56wLPDSZ7XKEAzkv4PArsBWuFhAHr2PrXLfxq/594PB2bB@2riwSc73sdIw6NBIt7eHaGo0GlFhZRKL8ePJWqLX1AD6obsNSydInx9nDsc4zHzpt1N40dw6jFzB0DzMzREFAPYLSSjzNuxf@@MSUArylyNBLRt0p7XzMZQ58evIbx8@bmtcj8Xj4loT0ME2MOhBQVsVGYDXv4UsV5NSflaxQZGGZQs/epEgaxyU/l6yODdG3nKk6kSpmRkBrzICYUwrAaqv6ELgB0Z4OroDG6d@hDbzArKCC8p0M@x6EIfY1Rf3wZ9j@HX9iLmPohjVgTa7YMF5EUChpDcBscs@H/i4LhnU2PcxYS2YEn6I1z6J6YsjL/dGC7fZhzst5l3LQRU0NGzQhynOm2o2WI8HSXfO6FujJmCYNk7ecI5L0TyJ5r9rrLqeulN49oiZvBNgh9Rq03@xOYGrzIGnuDTxwG8m42JH@3RNfHgwto3tR9DIxdJ0NZTngQbQUrTUSbyTNYofb5AqEo8mvuJe7oZ53LZdgftaU1fWEXHHMiQKsptAZkOdgkfTGx0zFCu2p7Fzka2CBcXrYPCGLLyrxjS2Bpc5c2tt9166gRa9l8OVjcwOoD7fn797YFEfna0706B2LxLN9sQejz0MAvfSSKHUMF31aaMvmJTE0TTB9GrjlzyK32SCA6GWTCqQ4UWhiDA0mDucUAnB9jEX53F4OQG0Ia2A03oGAYJTeZ5X/oFU/3VpUlARAtBca/GlwrPlZqrXLG3vEFNWp@Y2TPunVcAPaXLPFh3c/Z/rBWupOUBuYhBfK1d1g0pVxKJlX1s8UyvuYFjEBYJ5dPOe8aiL7IvKg6dNXemK3oirwOy5Qm8JUpxUfgoHV3ymJ6eqfeFWFSiWa@tqLoV3Evtw39JXM13QOUCPGPeuzN93jI@sdKMLka/16BkpUrf1QmExoQ8KR5op9aihz2kboFsB5RTWMI2B26JpcoLqle2FTXkthqqhs/P0cZAGdkcIK@2jCsaAfU7ojVpknV/OEh4/kkpmcMatGRV41EFNurshkVol98hpMrpz5ZIEQA6bOG0RkD9XofcHTH8ZJFIa5p05djFz6jA5UBKYpZxhpaEJisl30fMxz4G870ZTJAOncnMxK152CFILNpLj3N2C3F0WXk1NPM6I7VrXfDJLds1b5ay4pO5PqzBOdn2qJg0aphc2ODoJoUHowopOZsH5pKoM3hvO0TYEiXtfqJ@NxboZEf4cOozXn2wbdHx/Rv9nbk03by7xXeckanVGjS0OsazU5bHZPodZ2eJLBVcx9cUz4gJLDvjFQG8vYEMZAXXYJqxqeMDMB4WSYBZPhG59a5TuL9r15vthshUrpMZhy3MoV8y7ExVoUFJmPdcqa58xmDln2jefulNwqhontYVKyBDZ6io4b5CX@IfJC7aFZh2vgSgNOc7G4BHLe6uPXli1HKcriCSxEjLyGuav6eC5onHgYko3FAACH@rRkxI2BlrsCacwYvgPUG4l@J4UJJwfxV@DyosWgiwnBWs/7GVMwzSBdAcx8BbIA0HPDeXN0m9@zwAF6KoXOQbBLcgWfBy2OPvHlcsDxpUQ99WS7ZRWekR1z1552AoPTsPPpYNFmu@RD8xCP2fHKRK1Sx7Dtl6DYCIC1BXzWgTG2KzHb3KoADr5vt7EnUWjt0JZC3dyq@Ofdmg@jlr5Xa0f2M6PIJqR/BylnHE1S0m9f@j4POw/KnlCuOlGFSdOD2Z1k32UPCfv8FLO927aXb2nMcnLBj6HtGnisxMDzDZhTQh3dl2jCDW38xiyhL0Yub/JTk9fZhpX0Q8Qj@WapMNL0Ip4spEvr0SkFA3S82JFvizGemkTz1BYG6UaUsQvGYcU3aMvCTC91av6BM0fxkF6sUvKJQrmt@3MrGg@TOO9EPZ6ztfd8XzKFUi@sSZ3e@fMXc/AMZr1OZ2Oa1kTS70vhztsVgEt89jmbPeScoOKTSOfTa036AeiaTWlSNUyh34k5q0Ej9ZkJV5xR3i4lKX7CgyZ5yMEqUCm1qmpLA7YVJevFj@O5q2aTBOWkP6@z8x6umDtRpQGSB9/osgSJV1V8UqjPJbq5BLu@YgP/jnmNx5ZA5UNN4S2v9/2kQmW1i@k518cEB/tcIfvTP7FbScfc6pFTZO945S/HuJZoW696zp2d9etj5l@DAF08xntM4sEjf7YQcmbr86UzXsNsQZkRUQ8oz9dYLgF9P2KQngK47iFKuTDMPe17XlcMk6bCPaFZZ0Ik0JZ4Yr0kOdvFiGcRD6G2vVS/w00uCp0dmPZ12rZz34vPgO2LKSmLHWVGO9g71EuBuMauOWH2khNX6i0OHToYeBht/2TJkMvY5Nkc@FRMmWJlxX/pMPc7SiRKzu2hq/B4MLqz4sGpAhUqhmxME5ZzbxzG9@S9AnvCRe4tL3PxDV095A4Kb3HB6JUBSEwYNJmLbkXevxvt1h1o3953nlrCvtjRQ5kogZZRV0qi8A0u03Af9haj1HjGTuva9jExC/MJox64G@Z2o/XgpNFCuXFlR9ktQTmKbecYnDKM5UbUcabHxPm0nOaXHgnYD@z1lU2mBuH3HOcjgWpkk5@dc6iVFE/DOrNe5h2lSdg5mdM5Tm8Pzp@DsVXxEvWEG16i1zGOdypQQYMsdH2cxsQtgnK8qOFMjeuFFal4mEtiL8nXYqBmwQ0r0UH/F0bBKKpoSHQ4z6lP7uS5qLLTY4rh4oUlpajs/TrzjIFoyNY1Js2wJvsNXuWjj3//BvYmPcQnfCtziscWXpqZnoVNTwfA4JD2DCMlDSn8Wgk5qeS@Eb3IKTHwRaskmGAa/YM3L0ziohC11u5d6aUWlDNxBSZZL@kSryDZ643gb4DxJIjt8Pxr2@7NXINyLO25i4ItyHN8LXpOpUME45ujnYBcQztZg3J0DBGQCyKdDry/AX6BN/KE9fZUU@qYWAo96JYwiVaHZunAgH917TfdwJVeGAO4bM60X8WFSb7LbILDTCdam@3Y5eu6b7jSyYh8bS8eCMovDQy7pG3N6WkcOh@e1btldWMyGHzxhX5vOSvsHUyIelCk9xGvbM29NQE9ubfmyK9qXMw8eHphYNTuvBWVjDD7vAzKhIb@PZ3719G9MWdEpCEzoaDOMz9IxcHc@nUUxjDZn3gdX9j1zJ75m4ckhtkjNV8JdANVlaz/re2DWbuqklHwaXIPa0PRtZNqqZX7IFwAUHXPURssEV5LhZmRHC8eWWkJvuiaXzpe4sHlQUykFHi7n9364dMLy7ioEBbs/Hu6BiZ@fKltdBfBNKxPKTt4EBEoC0OleFDaFaMQFgaKzWcE5UGU68x6R6OnA/NFO2DNm6NTzBQAfgHr8qoJjW@sTaZ@6hDHzT6nc60xg3afGzi4e6kJ96UErQjvv3KHKt6O3BIYgmrHCCy8KPRpuVMVs7f5wdbz6DFwP9h7JIiLwhQoekGht4gS/cBBaKqnFfYH7Y3p0@zh4V6uYH1c/qwf69jmHvccl9aU8Wr22Mne8Ih3MDP/2iRniRb3PQjbD4szVDn4ptEqhy70e7XhpjtQJpZ7zDsN9baxXJ74W/TFMOcd17dCTC8UGsFhRrW7iNKKhNu@AmRcdpQBikZCPxSvT5WajR@Nnrq8rmKPKPIGeTcoxsiN9wk@u1Ry20vjZKpltdmW8jF2RYKNj5CjKem9WRkn@zwLe/UJTK4TfXQ@@xjvrvew0eUWrBQwZex5g7irhPXyUaiVCLYp3YOpgosxNcH4AIMlysjbRoEFE7gIaseOrNmUhBEgQCpn6hFja6D5M7MAiWTpyUeYKm6cIcMIp6FtZbrco@HcpxVhfEli1KXX1oEa/7qFm1ntundjw0kBWk4/HQ5g5drq4b7H8RxqypVRSmqHq01FusWrTkQC1F3TCfuD8@IIb5DkmyEPsNxM66ukbPjZDDH6tpbPybOtrhEdhGtFfRBrGkQvN97T8I0uGABK5sNkODB6SvQFeCMeyIkOHcW38fFbCVLv6P2OB3E22zq@rcS/TwdgiRsHMi64@8pvp20rN7xV9sAqORr8R6YOyMRuXj2D/mvfQ3wAx5xrxx3ZiCXgn4LMgb7aqUdYaBM10beGHVpJfTa1Kc1ifiT2uBRV2wuCVHR9TpSvO9opLILYNnS7RnR1kWjiI0gnv3SA6AC/D4o/8TxnJupa97Y737Ea41Wm8BOppiM5N9qXxZ/97bXwUeQmsoW0M0jfsHpkT7pFNmaOh6/3vdMgWzpNuugqTDQZOalxQldCDXfCs74XVlfryLK57iSeE50FPnrA9Mk2IWlPOev0Lao3bMNi4XbGyKOttTw9Yu/qqPAQKc6euGQaku5C3WwoJy4JgrfHGAATOQQVtQl4YDLNdnLO64Qypw0cGmZupv5JAutKnDpFBfMTgZtppRfXdJKKIoR3B0RezRAI7XV3aQ3bZNdSn9JOJ3abyv7FQvq1nUzikDteY9bzrtu@EvnUNvcxmnRS1FBIAqWvkzbJBfQg2uzulksybDR47xQ6bHVTn3SPA2vJ5aowp95NcnZ2eWxIfuQqnYqJ@kmAdYwGDGnCI3nkd4oJ9Ah9JODoKUHkeEUpCJxcNvZjkt5yM0uLJHsQYuQ2Krzt@HRwZczkQ8tKp4fjzSxarvrVhvpBVECuyOXfspH0VLQpJB2qpSNy@nar3uzfK/ScUh/GuRqfP6pafdwmdVMLtppNLrYlIBLzeWq584IFdSjgMVaT6zDYlDrWb@Dwmme22eJSRunyOicPDyYxXr1qeueB8RIjbYa44jALxqoqU1sYgtzsMUXZOpvpIQGlpaM@HB6UB74X41GC8k4M72CwqrG73glvudeKvtOakzktGh/Ja7fHzlBH2ELzTLbtyH2LdmyA/ZHi3BuLDlmveqfh9KlYsFaPFvui7jnkMacPD5Suk4cDMAKR@asJnH6KqruGf8PwniOrzYeDumNqHP25IhEn8xewBLcfINpueMwgHaZdVo8/PmwIwh689UWfn4XXT1bbIMmLjte2@2SIM7CFBulG9zasYAsHL17p5YzbHEhyp1r4ZnRl/e7R@RiNpQveMLCMMBvkBJph8kr4Gef8Y@8Gl97fRoAXonAEN7wYAJCwj0xoWEkcp5fNsSBFNTI9B2fJF23/HkzNVe1au/OJePeaPiNsQ1YBQUT6DrBuvvcxtDQYxRLwyK9ZCLu0I9CYVd7pvwMREmJy76av8OZgHQ73aLhv/qDvoch67MQmdtg0gEGiWL4udThkGjUf5BqaP5IglNYUXSkpaa4qJwB9cchATfxCH/@1RxwTfxphBRaS2vdnGODi0MVst6CYYRLzrh7vwLhwUXCD8my0OPOYuu3D7e9p9DTYrOZIqV2L7daIp0S@NQhO1qF7iA7DjJ9N9VDGLwXKzX60wZEDoQgx3ddwsHsH5G7O1/iMk@Q/4h/TWcpRl8t4/wbEmOQ1Xr0vDk5o0Upz1TKw5h3r1mjB@XPc46GBaFTbdDZ535Rr2ZSHhjQgM528nP6TICF8AGaOAeHxiOTFe2GzAMw48/UhG59tOoqSANBwPPg42D4UOsFrcWM/egnLZbSB8V49lO5yT952dzIMr1YYYkEDIff5fw).

Comment: Yours is the solution I considered to incorporate in my code, but since Regex has not yet been covered by the instructor, I went ahead with another solution without the regex. But yours was the one I originally had asked for. Just one single regex incorporating everything. Kudos to you, and much thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I also learned something new thanks to your question. Happy New Year :)

Comment: Happy New Year buddy... Thanks.