# How does a double "for" work in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So, for a background of the problem from where this question emerges, kindly refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049006/matching-states-and-cities-with-possibly-multiple-words).

As the accepted answer suggested, I went ahead with the provided code and was able to accomplish what I initially wanted. But making a dictionary was not my final goal. My ultimate aim with that dictionary was to transform it into a DataFrame, which I was able to. 
Here is what I did:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(([st, cty] for st, cty in dic.items() for cty in dic[st]), 
                    columns = ["State", "City"])
```

For your ready reference, the `dic` variable is as follows:

```
{'Alabama': ['Auburn',
  'Florence',
  'Jacksonville',
  'Livingston',
  'Montevallo',
  'Troy',
  'Tuscaloosa',
  'Tuskegee'],
 'Alaska': ['Fairbanks'],
 'Arizona': ['Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tucson'],
 'Arkansas': ['Arkadelphia',
  'Conway',
  'Fayetteville',
  'Jonesboro',
  'Magnolia',
  'Monticello',
  'Russellville',
  'Searcy'],
 'California': ['Angwin',
  'Arcata',
  'Berkeley',
  'Chico',
  'Claremont',
  'Cotati',
  'Davis',
  'Irvine',
  'Isla Vista',
  'University Park, Los Angeles',
  'Merced',
  'Orange',
  'Palo Alto',
  'Pomona',
  'Redlands',
  'Riverside',
  'Sacramento',
  'University District, San Bernardino',
  'San Diego',
  'San Luis Obispo',
  'Santa Barbara',
  'Santa Cruz',
  'Turlock',
  'Westwood, Los Angeles',
  'Whittier'],
 'Colorado': ['Alamosa',
  'Boulder',
  'Durango',
  'Fort Collins',
  'Golden',
  'Grand Junction',
  'Greeley',
  'Gunnison',
  'Pueblo, Colorado'],
 'Connecticut': ['Fairfield',
  'Middletown',
  'New Britain',
  'New Haven',
  'New London',
  'Storrs',
  'Willimantic'],
 'Delaware': ['Dover', 'Newark'], .... all the other states with their city names
```

The output that I got after running the above code is as follows (a screenshot):
[image]

My query is: Although I got the desired output, and although I formulated that "DataFrame comprehension", so to speak, myself, I do not fully understand the double `for`.

Can someone please explain how exactly does a `for` inside another `for` work in these kind of situations. I am a beginner in Pandas.

Comment: Damn it... I didn't know they deduct points for redundancy in question. A handsome pro level dude with a reputation of 169K just marked my question as duplicate. Buddy, with a reputation score of just 18, I am no competition for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a generator and has nothing to do with Pandas.

The term `([x, y] for x in q for y in p)` is a Python generator.  You can assign this to a variable, say `g = ([x, y] for x in q for y in p)` and then iterator over it:

```
for element in g:
    print(element)
```

Pandas accepts generators at this point and iterates over them to get all values for the `DataFrame`.

The double `for` is evaluated like this:

```
for x in q:
    for y in p:
        yield [x, y]
```

So what this generator produces is a flat list of all the combinations of the elements in `q` and `p`.