# Creating two column dataframe from one column series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series with data of States and Cities. First comes a State and underneath It all of its cities. Then another state with its cities under it and so on. How can I transform that series into a Dataframe like [‘State’, ‘City’].
This is my code:

```
U_towns = pd.read_table('university_towns.txt', header = None).rename(columns = {0 :'Borrador'})
U_towns = U_towns['Borrador'].str.split('(', n=2, expand = True).rename(columns = {0 :'Borrador'})
U_towns['State?'] = U_towns['Borrador'].apply(lambda x: 'State' if 'edit' in x else '')
U_towns = U_towns[['Borrador','State?']]
```

[image: This is the result of my code]

Dont know how to move States and cities to diferent columns in a way where each city has its state in a column next to it

Comment: Are these columns to be in text file or they are to be array/list/dicionary?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386443/create-pandas-dataframe-from-txt-file-with-specific-pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
df['State']=df.loc[df['State?']=='State','State?']
df.State=df.State.ffill()
df=df[df['State?']!='State']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use a Dictionary consisting of Series in this case. For example :

```
#Series with cities 
data_1 = np.array(['city_1','city_2','city_3','city_4'])
state_1 = pd.Series(data_1)

data_2 = np.array(['city_5','city_6','city_7','city_8'])
state_2 = pd.Series(data_2)

#Making a dictionary of states
dict = {
      "State_1": state_1,
      "State_2": state_2,
     }
```