# Using Pandas to import multiple sections from a single text file with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, parsing, text

Trying to import a text file with the following structure:

```
$NUMS 008
$STOM
%DATE 21-09-2011
%SSD  1000
<+000.0 +000.0 +000.0 +040.5>
<+000.0 +000.0 +000.2 +041.3>
<+000.0 +000.0 +000.6 +042.8>
<+000.0 +000.0 +001.0 +044.7>
<+000.0 +000.0 +001.4 +047.2>
...
$ENOM 
$STOM
%DATE 21-09-2011
%SSD  1000
<+000.0 +000.0 +000.0 +040.9>
<+000.0 +000.0 +000.1 +041.4>
<+000.0 +000.0 +000.5 +042.9>
<+000.0 +000.0 +000.9 +044.8>
<+000.0 +000.0 +001.3 +047.2>
<+000.0 +000.0 +001.7 +050.0>
<+000.0 +000.0 +002.1 +053.7>
...
```

The first line is the number of measurements then $STOM indicating start of measurement, couple for lines for measurement details, and then the guts in the four columns inside <> until $ENOM signifying end of measurement.

The next one starts straight after.

Can I use Pandas read_table for this, or do i separate out each measurements into different txt files using the $ENOM and $STOM delimiters before importing into pandas?

My expected output would be the following tables:

```
PDD01:
    x      y      z      pdd
    +000.0 +000.0 +000.0 +040.5
    +000.0 +000.0 +000.2 +041.3
    +000.0 +000.0 +000.6 +042.8
    +000.0 +000.0 +001.0 +044.7
    +000.0 +000.0 +001.4 +047.2

PDD02:
    x       y     z      pdd
    +000.0 +000.0 +000.0 +040.9
    +000.0 +000.0 +000.1 +041.4
    +000.0 +000.0 +000.5 +042.9
    +000.0 +000.0 +000.9 +044.8
    +000.0 +000.0 +001.3 +047.2
    +000.0 +000.0 +001.7 +050.0
    +000.0 +000.0 +002.1 +053.7
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: thanks, I've edited to add

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Would the answered question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386443/create-pandas-dataframe-from-txt-file-with-specific-pattern give you some thoughts?